# Q Android layout android:alpha?

Tags: android-layout

What effect does the alpha api have on the layout? I don't see any effect by the option in any way.

How can I set a background transparency for the background transparency

Comment: Alpha goes from #00 (fully-transparent) to #FF (fully opaque).
When setting a color #FFFFFF, add 2 hex codes to define the alpha.
For example, #000000 will be same as #FF000000 (full white), whereas #00000000 will be fully-transparent, and #99000000 half-white-transparent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in your xml:

```
android:background="#00000000"
```

The first 2 numbers are Alpha, followed by R,G,B.